# What is the definition of distant family?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I am not sure whether or not family collocates with distant, but my teacher gave me a list of words and phrases to write definitions for. I searched the internet for the definition of distant family but it was all in vain. I really hope you can help

Answer (score 5):

It's a recognized use:
[American Heritage Dictionary *distant*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=distant)

> 4. Far apart in relationship: *a distant cousin.*

[Merriam-Webster *distant*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/distant)

> 2 : separated in a relationship other than spatial *a distant cousin*

The meaning would exclude *immediate family*, i.e. mothers, fathers, children, aunts, uncles, close cousins, etc., but I don't know that there is a formal definition of how distant a distant relative would have to be. I don't think a first cousin would be distant.

Comment: I agree. I think the word itself is quite subjective, but my ‘close family’ (for me) would be people who I am directly related to, while distant family are people who I am not directly linked to (cousin, uncle, grandmother, etc.)

Comment: Agreed! Usage of “distant” to describe family seems like more of a statement of personal feelings towards those family members than an objective statement, i.e. it’s totally based on how close you feel to certain family members.

Comment: @AnnabethYeung - not subjective. I might hate my brother but he is still a close relative.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I find that subjective nonetheless. If I was estranged from my brother, I would personally no longer include him in “close family.” It does depend on context of usage.

Comment: @AnnabethYeung - in contexts such as genealogy, the sociology of the family, studies of kinship, etc, the 'distance' of a familial relationship is not a subjective thing dependent on the feelings of the people involved. Thus, in that sense, my third cousin is more distant than my brother, even if I hate my brother and love the cousin. I believe this formal, standard meaning is what the original question is about.